# Integrate $ \int \frac{x^4 +1}{x^6 - 1}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate

$$ \int \frac{x^4 +1}{x^6 - 1}\, \mathrm dx$$

I have tried using partial fractions but to no use. Thanks for help.

Comment: hint: $x^6-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use that $$\frac{x^4+1}{x^6-1}=\frac16\,{\frac {-2\,x-1}{{x}^{2}+x+1}}-\frac13\, \left( x+1 \right) ^{-1}+\frac16
\,{\frac {2\,x-1}{{x}^{2}-x+1}}+\frac13\, \left( x-1 \right) ^{-1}.
$$

Comment: thanks..1/3 is easy to find..how to go about others? should i take lcm.

Comment: @J.Deff: which is of the form $$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$, so easy!

Comment: Yes.  But how to find f'(x) using easy method because when i take lcm it becomes too long

Comment: Use that  $$(x^2+x+1)'=2x+1$$

Comment: But how did you find numerator first ?

Comment: Your result looks like that $$-1/6\,\ln  \left( {x}^{2}+x+1 \right) +1/3\,\ln  \left( x-1 \right) +1
/6\,\ln  \left( {x}^{2}-x+1 \right) -1/3\,\ln  \left( x+1 \right) 
$$

Comment: use substitution $f(x)=u$ to see $$\int \frac{f'(x)\; dx}{f(x)}=\int \frac{du}{u}=\ln(u) +c$$

Comment: How to find that C and D , $$ \frac{Cx+D}{x^2 + x + 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe that partial fractions is the easiest way to do this. Note:
$$(x^6-1)=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$
so you will want to do the partial fractions of:
$$\frac{x^4}{(x-1)(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}$$